# How to update the version of our android app in the playstore market

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, android-version

Sorry, I was a noob on this field. I use an eclipse to make an android app, and I need an answer about how to update the version of my app. Also, does the update replace everything in the project?

Comment: where have you reached with this ? would appreciate if you reply :)

Answer (score 1):

You go to the [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) just like the first time, and upload a new .apk.

This means you're completely replacing the app, but not anything else you've set up in the console, such as preview images and description text.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is publish your newly built APK in your Android Developer Console. The old APK is replaced with the new one. Remember to update the `android:versionCode` element in your manifest. You have to increment it by +1. This way when your users open the Play Store app on their devices, they will receive a notification that the application needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Developer console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/) page and upload the new .apk file.
Make sure in the new apk, android:versionCode (in Manifest file) is bumped. Otherwise you will get an error.
In the Developer console page both versions will be available. You can choose which app version you want in the field.